# Exceção ao adicionar o usercontrol mais de uma vez

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Olá.
Tenho um user control de newsletter e ele é adicionado em vários lugares dentro do projeto, para cada página em que ele é chamado, é definido uma propriedade para inserir o e-mail em um determinado grupo de e-mails (`GrupoEmailNewsletter`). Acontece que agora além das páginas internas o mesmo UC estará na `MasterPage`, onde começou a dar problemas.

Na master é registrado e chamado:

```
<%@ Register Src="../UserControl/BoxNewsletter.ascx" TagName="BoxNewsletter" TagPrefix="uc3" %>
<uc3:BoxNewsletter ID="boxNewsletter" runat="server" GrupoEmailNewsletter="Geral" />
```

E na página `GrupoA.aspx` também é registrado e chamado:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="uc5" Src="~/Include/UserControl/BoxNewsletter.ascx"  TagName="Newsletter" %>
<uc5:Newsletter id="ucNewsletter" runat="server" GrupoEmailNewsletter="GrupoA" />
```

Quando acesso a página `GrupoA.aspx`, acontece o seguinte erro:

```
ERRO DO SISTEMA:
Exceção do tipo 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' foi acionada.
Uma exceção foi acionada pelo destino de uma chamada.
Já existe uma entrada com a mesma chave.
```

Localizei os ids e não tem iguais. O que mais seria este erro?

Comment: Pode ser um id do seu UserControl ele vai ser duplicado se você usar na MasterPage e depois usar em outra página que herdar da MasterPage.

Comment: @MarconcilioSouza obrigada, é exatamente isto. Nesse User Control de Newsletter possui validações, neste casso o id da `Master` não foram adicionados aos `RequeredFieldValidator`. Adicionei a propriedade `ClientIDMode="AutoID"` em todos os `RequeredFieldValidator` do UC e funcionou corretamente.

Comment: ok, você pode posta como fez isso como resposta, assim outros que tiverem o mesmo problema saberão como resolver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O `UserControl` de newsletter que desenvolvi possui validações. Utilizo o `RequiredFieldValidator` para verificar se o campo é vazio. 
As páginas que herdam da `MasterPage` tem o `name` modificado, os componentes de validação do `UserControl` não tiveram o `name` modificado, neste caso eu adicionei a propriedade `ClientIDMode="AutoID"` nos componentes `RequiredFieldValidator` para alterar o id.

```
 <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvNomeNewsletter" runat="server" Display="None"
    ErrorMessage="Informe seu nome." ControlToValidate="txtNomeNewsletter" SetFocusOnError="true"
    ValidationGroup="vgrNewsletter" ClientIDMode="AutoID"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Assim, o id do elemento que está na página herdada da master page fica: `ctl00_cphMasterPortal_ucBoxNewsletter_rfvNomeNewsletter`

O elemento que está na masterpage: `ctl00_boxNewsletter_rfvNomeNewsletter`

Não ocasionando o erro de ID duplicado.